# Inline styling in Rails 4 erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, inline-styles, html-safe

So I am stuck with a small issue while migrating a legacy project from `Rails 3.2` to `4.2`
Inside one of our views (erb), the code (`Rails 3.2`)

```
html_safe(truncate(job_profile.description + '&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="#999">[ ' + list.join(', ') +' ]</font>', :length => 100))
```

produces the following text:

[image: Rails_3_version]

if it's not clear `job_profile.description` resolves to `Test` and likewise `list.join(', ')` to `English Listening Comprehension`
Now the same code in Rails 4.2 produces the following:

[image: Rails_4_version]

Tried many options to reproduce the original result but didn't succeed. Suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead

```
truncate(job_profile.description + '&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="#999">[ ' + list.join(', ') +' ]</font>', :length => 100).html_safe
```

**or**

```
raw(truncate(job_profile.description + '&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="#999">[ ' + list.join(', ') +' ]</font>', :length => 100))
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Have already tried using `raw`/ moving `html_safe` to the end. Didn't work though. Thanx for the input anyways !!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I guess I found a solution, using a `truncate` over `html_safe` that includes special characters was producing problems, when the entire text including the `nbsp;` and inline styling was cut short due to truncate.

Switching the order of `html_safe` and `truncate` somewhat solved the issue. Now it would truncate first and then apply `html_safe`. But still was producing undesirable results when total length including all special characters increased my truncate limit. A little effort produced a result which was almost correct.

```
html_safe(job_profile.description.truncate(100) + '&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="#999">[ ' + truncate(list.join(', '), length: 100-(job_profile.description.length)) +' ]</font>')
```

Little more customisation, taking into accounts the three dots `...` every truncate produces, and one would get the exact result as needed.